# Javascript ignore html tag and add space to the string after every 2 characters

Tags: javascript, reactjs, regex, ecmascript-6

I have a string with HTML  in between. What I want to achieve is add a space in between after every 2nd character.

For example for input like below -

```
'<span>234567</span><span>34526754</span>'

'<span>23 45 67</span><span>34 52 67 54</span>'
```

How can I achieve this in JavaScript?

Comment: Do not use regexes to parse the string. Use the [DomParser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser), walk the DOM to find text nodes, manipulate their `nodeValue` property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
let str = '<span>234567</span><span>34526754</span>'

str.match(/(?<=\<span>).*?(?=<\/span>)/g).forEach(s=>{
 str = str.replace(s, s.match(/.{2}/g).join(' '))
})
console.log(str)
```